# How to split string by comma and newline (\n) in Java?

Tags: java, string, split

So I have this string :
"New York,USA,1000\n" +
"City,World,2000\n";

I need to split it first by newline and then by comma, so at the end I get an array of strings that is like this: New York has index 0, USA index 1, 1000 index 2, World index 4 and so on..I tried using
`String[] newline = string.split("\n")` and then declaring a new array of strings called result ( giving it 1000 characters randomly ) and making a for loop like this:

```
String[] result = new String[1000];
for (String s : newline){
  result=s.split(",");
}
```

But it doesn't work properly. Any help, please?

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work :/

Comment: share the sample input that you are trying to split

Comment: @Kopite1905 Well, I tried it and [it works](https://rextester.com/STTQPJ8557).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "New York,USA,1000\n" + "City,World,2000\n";
        String[] newline = string.split("\n");
        String[] result = new String[1000];
        //first loop
        result = newline[0].split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        //second loop
        result = newline[1].split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
/*
output:
[New York, USA, 1000]
[City, World, 2000]
 */
```

**result would be overrided instead of append.**

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "New York,USA,1000\n" + "City,World,2000\n";
        String[] newline = string.split("\n");
        String[] result = new String[1000];
        int index = 0;
        for (String s : newline) {
            for (String t : s.split(",")) {
                result[index++] = t;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
/*
output:
New York USA 1000 City World 2000 
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Different operating system has a different new line

Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

- UNIX or Mac \r
- Windows \r\n

  ```
  String[] lines = text.split("\\r?\\n");
  for (String line : lines) {
      System.out.println("line  : " + line);
      String[] words = line.split(",");
      System.out.println("words : " + words);
  }
  ```

Comment: OP specifically used "\n" both in the title of the question and in the input string though.

Comment: but you didn't specify the OS you are using

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 8 or higher try try something like:

```
String str =  "New York,USA,1000\n" + "City,World,2000\n";
String[] result = Pattern.compile("\n")
                         .splitAsStream(str)
                         .map(s -> s.split(","))
                         .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                         .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly:

```
import re

stringobject = "New York,USA,1000\n" + "City,World,2000\n"

emptylist = []
for str_obj in stringobject.splitlines():
    o = str_obj.split(sep=",")
    emptylist.append(o)

print(emptylist)

[['New York', 'USA', '1000'], ['City', 'World', '2000']]
```

Which is a list of list and can be accessed:

```
print(emptylist[0][0])
'New York'
```